# Data coming from bluetooth socket not clean, buffer not cleared?

Tags: java, android, sockets, arduino, buffer

I'm working on a project with Arduino and bluetooth hc 05 module. When I send data from Arduino to my android app using bluetooth socket I don't receive it clean.

simple arduino code:

```
void loop(){
 mySerial.println("300");
 delay(1000);
 mySerial.println("750"); 
 delay(1000);
}
```

I should receive 300 and i put it in a textView and after 1s I receive 750 and I put it in textView and so on .. but what I actually receive is numbers concatinated ! like this : 3007 or 5030 or 0750

My receiving methode :

```
public void receiveMsg(){

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
    System.out.println("socket still conneceted ? " + btSocket.isConnected());
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = btSocket.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream mmInStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);

        length = mmInStream.read(buffer);
        String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, length);            
        mMq2.setText(readMessage);
        //inputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I call this methode from here :

```
public void listn(){
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       while(getLifecycle().getCurrentState().isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)){
           receiveMsg();
           try {
               sleep(1000);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
    }
};
thread.start();
}
```

What should I do to receive data correctly ? I thought problem comming from buffer not being cleared so i tried to clear it but not working.

Comment: The size of your byte buffer is 4 bytes so it's trying to read 4 bytes of data. Do you know that your data source will always be 3 bytes? Change `byte[] buffer = new byte[4];` to `byte[] buffer = new byte[3];`

Comment: Yes I thought about it, because data source will be always 3 bytes. but that's not really practical, what if data had to be variant ? but as for my project it will work, Thank you sir.

Comment: If your inbound data is of variable length then you really need a transport scheme where the first n bytes defines the length of the expected stream. You seem like you're trying to solve variable length streams by using sleeps to time the input with the sender but that's not wise.